# Displaying different values in same DocuSign tab

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to pre populate a locked text tab with different values for different recipients using docusign-api?

I passed the same tab with different values for different recipients but the values just overlap each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [document visibility feature](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) for this.
That would require the document to be duplicated for each user and then the tabs for each document would be only visible for the user that can view that document.